# Please make sure it has an appropriate 'as' value and it is preloaded intentionally

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On a website I am using a script that send a request, but on inspect element its showing this message:

The resource "RESOURCE" was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

and the request is not getting sent.
How do i fix this

Comment: Instead of describing what your code does, why don't you post it?

Comment: <script type="application/javascript" async
src="source"></script>

this is a custom script I am using so i dont think this will help

Answer (score 4):

In the page that this preload request is described, please make sure a function within the script file is called as part of the `DOMContentLoaded` event (which is earlier than the window.onloadevent) or earlier . This ensures the function is initialized within some time.

without additional code - preload snippet, usage snippet within an HTML page or an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - Only directional help can be provided.

Best of luck!